# How should we name tests in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, naming-conventions

How should we name tests in Visual Studio 2010?  We want all tests to be associated with the project that they are testing, but also want all tests to have a common naming format to differentiate them from the source code projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit test naming best practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

I mean you probably just want to keep all your tests in a seperate visual studio project
and name it .Tests.

So all the test classes will have namespace .Tests

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to highlight the guidelines and derive the conventions from them:
- Separate product code and tests code into two separate trees
- Make it extremely easy to find testing code for any production code (e.g. be able to run all tests which test some code)
- Separate different kind of tests fixtures (unit, system, stress, etc.)

Based on those guidelines I would:
1. Create the product directory tree without any reference to testing (say `Src/product/ns1/ns2`).
2. Create a similar tree for tests, with exactly the same general tree structure (say `Test/product/ns1/ns2`)
3. Have a single project for each testing fixture. That is a `ProjectUnitTest` contain the unit-tests of project `Project` and `NamespaceStressTest` contain stress tests for an entire namespace called `Namespace`, etc.