# How to Unit test JPA idclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit

I am struggling to write/understand a unit test for JPA inheritance @idClass in Intellij IDE. When running the test with code coverage, the IDE displays 5/6 method covered. But the class has only five methods. Where is the 6th method? What am I missing?

```
package com.beetlehand.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_attribute", schema = "beetlehand", catalog = "")
@IdClass(ProductAttributeEntityPK.class)
public class ProductAttributeEntity {
    private int productId;
    private int attributeValueId;

    /*** Getters and Setters ***/

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ProductAttributeEntity that = (ProductAttributeEntity) o;
        return productId == that.productId &&
                attributeValueId == that.attributeValueId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(productId, attributeValueId);
    }
}
```

And the unit test

```
package com.beetlehand.model;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class ProductAttributeEntityPKTest {
    @Test
    void testGetProductId() {
        ProductAttributeEntity entity = new ProductAttributeEntity();
        entity.setProductId(1);
        entity.setAttributeValueId(1);

        assertEquals(1, entity.getProductId());
    }
    @Test
    void testGetAttributeValueId() {
        /*** test logic ***/

        assertEquals(1, entity.getAttributeValueId());
    }
    @Test
    void testEquals() {
        /*** test logic ***/

        assertEquals(true, entity.equals(entity2));
    }
    @Test
    void testHashCode() {
        /*** test logic ***/

        assertEquals(entity2.hashCode(), entity.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the setters called in the unit tests?  Side bar: consider using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) which would remove the need to test.

Comment: I am using the wrong entity class. It should be ProductAttributeEntityPK class instead of ProductAttributeEntity class

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking each control in `if` statement increases the value of *coverage*. You can't get a *100% covarage* value because you do not provide all the controls in the `equals` method. You must provide all the controls (same object, null object, different class object) in unit test methods.

> **!!!** You must check null object firstly otherwise you will get an **NullPointerException** when you submit a null object.

I also want to make suggestions for testing. Firstly, I suggest you do research on *unit test naming conventions*. For example, you can review this title -> [Unit test naming best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices)

```
@Test
void equals_WhenObjectIsNull_ShouldReturnFalse() {

}

@Test
void equals_WhenObjectIsSame_ShouldReturnTrue() {

}
```

My other suggestion is that you can create the entity object under [`@Before` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall) and reduce the code lines.

```
public ProductAttributeEntity entity;
 
@Before
public void setUp() {
    entity = new ProductAttributeEntity();
    entity.setProductId(1);
    entity.setAttributeValueId(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mustafa, for the idea.