# Should I avoid having multiple different 'common/util.py' files? If so, how?

Tags: python

I currently have some tests that are structured like this:

```
tests/
    category_a/
        sub_category_1/
            test_file_a11.py
            test_file_a12.py
        sub_category_2/
            test_file_a21.py
            test_file_a22.py
        sub_category_3/
            test_file_a31.py
            test_file_a32.py
    category_b/
        sub_category_4/
            test_file_b41.py
            test_file_b42.py
        sub_category_5/
            test_file_b51.py
            test_file_b52.py
        sub_category_6/
            test_file_b61.py
            test_file_b62.py
```

Which works really well for what we need. In reality this breakdown makes more sense, and there are many more categories/files. This can also apply just to our non-test structure.

The problem is that I want to have multiple levels of shared code. Some code that should be shared between ALL tests, some just between tests in category_a, and some specific to sub categories. I can just add a common.py at each level, but then I end up with test_file_a32 using 3 different common files. It works, but I find it pretty confusing to read.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use classes and subclasses. The subclasses should be based on the `common.py` tests and will inherit all of the methods/functions available.

Comment: @Adi219 What would you name each file then?

Comment: `all_tests.py` just inside the `/tests` directory, `a_tests.py` just inside the `/tests/a` directory, and `subcat1_tests.py` inside the `/tests` directory. Alternatively, you could have one file containing all of these common tests just inside the `/tests` directory and just access the different tests from within the different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In industry, it's common for test teams to implement what you're describing using classes and subclasses. The parent class should be called `common.py`and its subclasses should contain their own specialised tests (the `common.py` tests would be inherited).

Comment: Makes sense. What would the naming structure be though? Top level is common.py, next level is category_a_common.py, then sub_category_common.py? Or is there a different convention that's commonly used?

Comment: @user3715648 See my comment on your question :)

Comment: @user3715648 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96297/what-are-some-popular-naming-conventions-for-unit-tests

Comment: @user3715648 Using underscores and the type of naming you're using is a common practice :)